# AngularFire2 returning [object Object]

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I am trying to figure out where everything's gone wrong. All my observables return [object Object].

My **sunshine.component.html**

```
<h4>Welcome {{username$}}</h4>
<ul>
<li *ngFor="let addsnote of addsnotes$ | async">{{ addsnote }}</li>
</ul>
```

My **sunshine.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable, FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2';

export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {
  private addsnotes$: FirebaseListObservable<string[]>;
  private username$: FirebaseObjectObservable<string>;
  private profileshow = false;
  addForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private af: AngularFire){
    this.addForm = new FormGroup({
      'addnote': new FormControl()
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    let user = firebase.auth().currentUser,
    userNamePath = `users/${user.uid}/username`,
    notesPath = `users/${user.uid}/addnote`;
    this.username$ = this.af.database.object(userNamePath);
    this.addsnotes$ = this.af.database.list(notesPath);
  }

  addSubmit(){this.addsnotes$.push('Billy Dee Williams');}

}
```

Portions of my Firebase **database**

```
{
  "users" : {
    "4twiyaFxVmaESXGWIfW4BwRXh893" : {
      "addnote" : {
        "-KSmWtpUSFXPCL4O3aKr" : "Do the dishes"
      },
      "useremail" : "majic@johnson.com",
      "username" : "majic"
    },
    "PYuSE6zyAENdKREZGTHm5VH1DXn1" : {
      "addnote" : {
        "-KSoZM7sH6X5ahMq7S5y" : "Du the dishes",
        "-KSoZMimZzm6ZGQowmuL" : "Du the dishes",
        "-KSouEXkc1UkyISGTCHd" : "Du the dishes"
      },
      "useremail" : "majohjn@asd.com",
      "username" : "asdasd"
    }
  }
}
```

A screenshot of **my page** (for the sake of clarity)

[image]

**EDIT** I have included a repo of my ongoing project here, so as to provide you all with as much info as possible. Hopefully it's useful.

https://github.com/emjayweb/demo

The respective files are in **src/app/profile/profile.component**. As this is completely WIP, please don't fuss about the logistics of it (guard routing, validation, etc).

The way this works is you enter some dummy data on the home page Create Account, then click on the Profile link on the navigation. You will probably have to refresh the page first. When you click on the button in the Profile route, you enter 'Billy Dee Williams' to your `addnote` array, and the view should reflect that.

Comment: You need a `| async` in the title as well, as FirebaseObjectObservable is also an async observable that needs to be unwrapped:  `<h4>Welcome {{username$ | async}}</h4>`. We're working on some ways to make this simpler with directives.

Comment: thanks for the info. I was wondering how I would format async with objects. This still does not solve my `[object Object]` issue unfortunately. I remain puzzled as to why this is happening.

Comment: Try piping it to json then and see what you've got. {{ username | async | json }}

Comment: I actually already got it. The answer is below. But I'm not allowed to check my own answer until tomorrow. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got the answer [from a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39738596/calling-arrays-in-firebase-using-angular-2/39762796?noredirect=1#comment66852488_39762796). What I had to do was add `$.value` tags to my HTML. In the case of my list observable, it would have been:

```
 <li *ngFor="let addsnote of addsnotes$ | async">{{ addsnote.$value }}</li>
```

And for my object observable, it would have been:

```
<h4>Welcome {{ (username$ | async)?.$value }}</h4>
```

Comment: Is above code will work in angular 4 also with latest version of angularfire2

Answer (score 1):

In the below code 'addsnote' is an array of object.

```
<li *ngFor="let addsnote of addsnotes$ | async">{{ addsnote }}</li>
```

Just Check the below code.

```
<li *ngFor="let addsnote of addsnotes$ | async">{{ addsnote[0] }}</li>
```

Then you can understand how to access the data.

Comment: For additional info, the empty bullet points I get using your code corresponds correctly with the amount of items I have in my database. So an `li` is being printed out. However, that `li` is empty. And adding or removing the respective list items changes the amount of empty `li` tags that I have in my code.